# informatica Post command task

Tags: informatica-powercenter

I am working with multiple source files with single source instance. I created three flat files and one destination table to experiment multiple sources. I am using ‘File list’ concept, for that I created a text file which contains all the flat file names. 
Example:

```
Filename : File_list.txt 
File content : Price1.txt 
Price2.txt 
Price3.txt
```

In the above example Price1.txt, Price2.txt and Price3.txt are flat file names. I specified File_list.txt as a source file while running the Workflow in Informatica. So it will iterate through all the flat files in the specified file (File_list.txt) and insert all the values to destination table. 
Now what I want to do is once data is inserted to the destination, I need to delete that source file in that directory location. 
How to achieve this?.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to write a custom script that will use the File_list.txt as input and perform the delete operations. You can then call it using `Post-Session Success Command` session component, or as a separate Command Task in the workflow linked using a `$YourSessionName.Status = SUCCEEDED` condition.